# Searching for multiple keywords using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, keyword

I'm going to search my database (SQL Server 2008) using a stored procedure. My users can enter keyword(s) in a textbox (keywords can be separated using `,` for instance).

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
keyword like N"%'+@SearchQuery%'%"
```

(`keyword` is a `nvarchar` column in my table, and `@SearchQuery` is the input to my stored procedure)

It works fine but what if user types several keywords: apple,orange, banana

Should I limit number of my keywords? How should I write my stored procedure if I have more than one keyword? How should I pass my user input to the stored procedure? I should pass `apple, orange, banana` as a whole phrase and then I should parse them in my stored procedure, or I should separate my keywords and send 3 keywords? How can I query these 3 keywords? A for loop?

What are best practices for performing such queries?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CTE to split the string of keywords in a temporary table and then use it as you like. The keyword list can even have numbers or any characters, like %$<> or what you want, just remember comma is the string separator

```
DECLARE @CommaSeparatorString VARCHAR(MAX),
        @CommaSeparatorXML XML
DECLARE @handle INT
SELECT @CommaSeparatorString = 'apple,orange,banana'
SELECT @CommaSeparatorString = REPLACE(REPLACE(@CommaSeparatorString,'<','$^%'),'>','%^$')
SELECT @CommaSeparatorXML   =   CAST('<ROOT><i>' + REPLACE(@CommaSeparatorString, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i></ROOT>' AS XML) 

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'$^%','<'),'%^$','>') AS ID
  FROM (SELECT @CommaSeparatorXML AS CommaXML) a
 CROSS APPLY CommaXML.nodes('//i') x(c)
```

Result:

```
  ID
------
apple
orange
banana
```

Answer (score 5):

Do the parsing of the keywords in your application. SQL is not the best place for string manipulation.

Send the keywords as a table valued parameter (ie : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/ ) then you aren't limited to a fixed number of keywords.

Add the wildcards to the parameter in the stored procedure

```
update @keywords set keyword = '%'+keyword+'%'
```

filter your results by joining your source data to this table

eg:

```
SELECT result
FROM source 
    INNER JOIN @keywords keywords 
         ON source.keyword LIKE keywords.keyword
```

Comment: Great answer, but this searches for any of the keywords, not all of the keywords.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on:
 * How big it's your database.
 * How often users will search for something.
 * How precise results users except.

`LIKE` is not performance daemon, especially starting with `%`.

Maybe you should try [full search text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)?

If you would like stay with `LIKE` (it will works only for small tables) I would try something like:

1. Split intput by `,` character (insert them into table as [podiluska](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684503/1483) suggested is a good idea).
2. Build query for each token and `UNION` all results. Or run it in loop for each token and insert results to temporary table.

If you need some precise results (i.e. only records matches all 3 words) you can select most matching results from temporary results built above.

Comment: I think LIKE is my best option, I think I should limit number of keywords and do something like what you said, thanks